# Как с помощью canvas реализовать экранную клавиатуру?

Tags: html5, canvas

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("draw");
var x = canvas.getContext("2d");
x.font = '32px Arial';
x.fillStyle = '#007439';
x.fillText("A", 15, 35);

$("#a").click(function() {
  var clone = $(this).clone();
  console.log(clone);
});
```

```css
 #stroka {
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
   left: 20px;
   right: 10px;
   height: 100px;
   background: white;
   padding: 5px;
   border: solid 1px black;
 }

 #a {
   position: absolute;
   top: 140px;
   left: 20px;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: white;
   padding: 5px;
   border: solid 1px black;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="stroka"></div>
  <div id="a" class="item">
    <canvas id='draw' width='50' height='50'></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на клавишу A с помощью мыши, символ А выводился в поле выше(как строка)?

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение, учитывающее ряд замечаний:

1. JQuery здесь совершенно не нужен.
2. Имеет смысл выполнить клавиатуру в виде набора полноценных кнопок (элементов `button`), а не псевдокнопок на `canvas`-ах.
3. Для запрета выделения текста необходимо вызывать `event.preventDefault()` в обработчике нажатия кнопки.
4. Абсолютное позиционирование заменено на относительное. Пусть обозреватель сделает всё за нас.

```js
"use strict";

var textLine;

function onLoad()
{
    textLine = document.getElementById("textLine");
}

function addChar(character)
{
    textLine.textContent += character;
}
```

```css
#textLine {
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}

 button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;

    cursor: pointer;
    font: 32px Arial;
    color: #007439;

    /* На случай, если необходимы именно белые кнопки с чёрной границей */
    /* background: white;          */
    /* padding: 5px;               */
    /* border: solid 1px black;    */
 }
```

```html
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <div>
        <div id="textLine"></div>
        <button onclick="addChar('a'); event.preventDefault()">A</button>
        <button onclick="addChar('b'); event.preventDefault()">B</button>
        <button onclick="addChar('c'); event.preventDefault()">C</button>
        <button onclick="addChar('∧'); event.preventDefault()">∧</button>
        <button onclick="addChar('∨'); event.preventDefault()">∨</button>
        <button onclick="addChar('¬'); event.preventDefault()">¬</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: а знаки конъюнкции или дизъюнкции, и отрицания?

Comment: @Светлана, обновил пример. При необходимости добавить другие кнопки делайте по аналогии.